# Tracking DB changes with Zend Framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zend-framework, release-management

I am trying to decide between the Zend Framework and Ruby On Rails for my web application.

If I go with ZF, I need the following:

- A way to incrementally track changes to my database, as with RoR's migration feature (001_something.sql, 002_something_else.sql).
- A place to put SQL for the next release of my software. At work in our custom PHP solution, we just have release.sql, which gets run, archived, and blanked out upon release.

ZF has Zend_Db_Schema_Manager, which does the same thing, but I'm not interested as its not official, complete, or maintained.

Is there an official mechanism that ZF provides for doing something similar to what I described?

*EDIT* I ended up going with Rails. Nothing compares.

Comment: Do you realise you have the completly different languages? :)

Answer (score 2):

We've been using [dbdeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/2008/04/21/php-and-dbdeploy/) and the respective Phing task for db migrations in our PHP projects and it works great for us. There also seems to be a new tool out there called [phpmig](http://github.com/davedevelopment/phpmig).

The proposal for Zend_Db_Schema_Manager has been archived in the meantime as I gather from looking at the [development wiki](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Db_Schema_Manager+-+Rob+Allen). I don't know think a best practice has emerged yet for db migrations with Zend Framework. I guess many are using doctrin's migration freature.

Comment: Hmm. I still don't want to wait. RoR's migration feature is mature as well, so I'll probably end up going with that.

Answer (score 0):

I use Zend Framework for our app in conjunction with the [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), which includes a migration tool that suits our needs just fine.

You should be able to use the migration tools without adopting the entire ORM framework. Also, before I found Doctrine, I had been evaluating [php-migrations](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-php-migrations/) as well. But to be honest, I think Doctrine is a lot more mature.

As far as choosing a framework, I don't think any one single feature should sway you. Find something you're comfortable using, can be supported, and can do what you need it to when your requirements change.